# Create range of years from start to end.

Tags: java

I'm looking for the simplest way to create range of years that I can put into a list starting with a from year and ending with an end year.

Example

```
String fromYear = "2010"
String toYear = "2014"
```

expecting to create a list of years `["2010","2011","2012","2013","2014"]`

No I know I need to convert the string to an Integer

```
Integer from = fromYear != null ? Integer.parseInt(fromYear) : null;
Integer to = toYear != null ? Integer.parseInt(toYear) : null;
```

From there I'm lost as for the most efficient way to complete this.

Comment: counting would be a good place to start.

Comment: Are you thinking for looping and incrementing up until you hit the toYear?

Comment: Yes, this is no different than outputing the numbers from 0 to 10. Your start and end conditions are just different.

Comment: I never gave a loop a thought, I was over thinking this entire thing thinking I would have to subtract the years then figure out the inbetween.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Takes `String` arguments, converts and returns `Integer` list:

```
public static List<Integer> range(String startYear, String endYear) {
    int cur = Integer.parseInt(startYear);
    int stop = Integer.parseInt(endYear);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (cur <= stop) {
        list.add(cur++);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Or if you need to return `String` list:

```
public static List<String> range(String startYear, String endYear) {
    int cur = Integer.parseInt(startYear);
    int stop = Integer.parseInt(endYear);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cur <= stop) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(cur++));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: What about the NumberFormatException that Integer.parseInt() throws?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen What about it? If you're running into that exception, then you aren't following the guidelines [put forth in the documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 5):

Here's what it's like with the new Java 8 streams API. I am going to assume that there is no use case where either year could be `null`, and will thus throw an error if one of them is:

```
String fromYear = "2010" ;
String toYear = "2014" ;

List<Integer> years =
        IntStream.rangeClosed
                (Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(fromYear)),
                 Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(toYear)))
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Steps correspond roughly to: ensure `fromYear` and `toYear` are both non-`null`, else throw an exception; convert `fromYear` and `toYear` to integers; create a stream of `int` values beginning with `fromYear` and ending with `toYear`; convert them into `Integer` instances (that's `boxed()`); and package them as a list.

Answer (score 3):

You should not create such a specific function that takes strings, it's normally better to have a range function that takes ints and convert the strings using `Integer.parseInt` as you already said in the question.

Then you can define your own function:

```
public static List<Integer> range(int from, int to) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = from; i <= to; ++i)
        list.add(i);
    return list;
}
```

Otherwise if you are using Java 8 take a look at [`IntStream.rangeClosed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-). You could also use Guava's [`Range`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html), they are nice because using iterators, they don't have to physically instantiate the list.

Comment: I can't wait to try java 8 Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Treat Date as a Date

```
String fromYear = "2010";
String toYear = "2014";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
List<String> listOfDates = new ArrayList();
Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
startCal.setTime(df.parse(fromYear));
Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
endCal.setTime(df.parse(toYear));
while (startCal.getTimeInMillis() <= endCal.getTimeInMillis()){
    java.util.Date date = startCal.getTime();
    listOfDates.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date).trim());
    startCal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
}
System.out.println(listOfDates);
```